# Destiny April update new missions

Tags: destiny

So recently with the new update in Destiny (2015Apr12) Variks has a new set of missions, or so I was told. After downloading the new update and even equipping some taken armor there are no missions available, I've reset my Xbox, logged in and out multiple times. Nothing has yet to appear I was told that you needed to complete the house of wolves story line and so I have. What I'm really hoping for that this is a bug and I'm not the only one experiencing this. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you finished The Taken King story missions? Also, I'm assuming your level 40. I'm not sure what's the specific problem in your case as the mission is available for me.

Comment: You might need to finish the missions that Varies gives you from TTK as well - not sure if that is a requirement or not.

Comment: I got them on my alts without finishing HoW or TTK. Did you check the Reef? That's where you get the missions.

Answer (score 2):

The latest [This Week at Bungie](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/44657/) says that you must do the following in order to unlock the quest chain in the April update:

> To unlock the new April Update Quests “At the Gates” and “Return to the Prison”, Characters must have reached Level 40 and completed the “Dread Patrol” Quest Step.

I think Dread Patrol is the mission Cayde-6 gives you when you finish the story missions in TTK.